# socket ip address and port in android

Tags: android, sockets, ip, serversocket

I am new to socket programming in android. I had implemented code from tutorial. I am confused with ip address and port. What should be ip and port to establish socket connection. I have tried with my **wifi ip address** and **1935** port and also tried with **localhost** . It gives me ENETUNREACH error. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Check your socket server for port number.

For example the following node js socket server listens on port **3000**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

For IP address, check the ip address of the hosting machine, not the wifi router.